# How do you initialize jquery select2 items when you are in "tagging" mode?

Tags: jquery, tags, jquery-select2, tagging

I am trying to figure out how to initialize [a jquery select2 item](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags) when i am in tagging mode (as i want to allow users to enter new items:

I see this example:

```
 $("#e12").select2({tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});
```

which works fine but I need to instantiate it with some entries already added.

but if i want to initialize with some existing items on page load, i tried doing something like this:

```
   var existingEmailAddresses= ["joe@abc.com","bill@abc.com"];

   $("#e12").select2({
            width: "600px",
            multiple: true,
            tags:["A", "B", "C"],
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                callback(existingEmailAddresses);
            }
        });
```

but that doesn't seem to be working.

How can you initialize entrying when you are using tagging mode?

### Edit

I also want to see if there is any hook to validate new tags added. In my case I want to make sure they are valid email addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var existingEmailAddresses = ["joe@abc.com", "bill@abc.com"];

$("#e12").val(existingEmailAddresses).select2({
    width: "600px",
    multiple: true,
    tags: ["A", "B", "C"]
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KBX4L/)

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I will accept your answer but i had a quick followup (i also updated the question).   Do you know if there is any support for validating new tags.  For example in one case people are entering in email addresses and i want to make sure any new tags created are valid email addresses

Comment: thanks for the jsfiddle.  One question i have is wouldn't that event affect all select2 items instead of this specific one (as i have many on a page and only want this to apply to this specific one)

Comment: @leora no... we are binding the handler to a single select2 element so it will affect only that element

Comment: ah, that makes sense (just got confused by the name) . .

Comment: Save my time :)

Answer (score 0):

In Select2 version 4.x, this got changed. 
Select2 is applied to a "select" tags instead of using the initSelection method, it uses a data adaptor. More info here https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html